# With mapping in laravel 7 app collect data

Tags: laravel

In laravel 7 app I use mapping when I need to collect columns in array

```
        $retArray['categoryLabels'] = Category
            ::get()
            ->map(function ($item) {
                return ['code' => $item->id, 'label' => $item->title];
            })
            ->all();
```

I wonder if there is some method(like pluck) for this purpose ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the categories are like

> code: web label: Web Development
>
> code: php label: PHP Programming
>
> code: javascript label: Javascript Frameworks

Use mapWithKeys

```php
$retArray['categoryLabels'] = Category::get()
    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
        return ['code' => $item->id, 'label' => $item->title];
    })
    ->all();
```

`mapWithKeys` will give output as

```php
//Value of $retArray['categoryLabels']
//similar to using pluck()

[
    'web' => 'Web Development',
    'php' => 'PHP Programming',
    'javascript' => 'Javascript Frameworks'
}
```

Another way

```php
$retArray['categoryLabels'] = Category::select('code', 'label')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

will give output as

```php
//Value of $retArray['categoryLabels']

[
    ['code' => 'web', 'label' => 'Web Development'],
    ['code' => 'php', 'label' => 'PHP Programming'],
    ['code' => 'javascript', 'label' => 'Javascript Frameworks']
]
```

Comment: Looks like mapWithKeys is different. I need to return array with 2 keys 'code' and 'label' to exlude internal closure

Comment: Help me understand properly - you need only code and label values for each record of Category and then assign an array of multiple records of Category which contains only two column with values to $retArray['categoryLabels'] - is that correct?

Comment: @PetroGromovo Have updated answer pls check and let me know